# DateBox hour/minute range limiting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, datebox

DateBox supports hour range limiting like so: 
`data-options='{"mode":"timebox", "validHours":[9,10,11,14]}'>`

How can I allow specific time ranges but block others? For example, I would like to block 10.00am-10.30am but allow 10.31am-11.00 am.

Comment: I assume (data-options='{"mode":"timebox", "validHours":[9,10:30,11,14]}'>) doesn't work. ??? If it doesn't then to get around it is to change the time to 10:31 when you choose 10 on the clock so you need some jquery to check if its 10 and then change the minutes to 31 and also stop it from going back to 30 and below if its at 10. If you provide some code for the datebox on Jfiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/ -- i can help you with the jquery.

Comment: Hmm.  I've not had this type of limiting requested before.  Can you be more specific?  For instance, is it only a *single* range you are looking for, or multiple?